# I keep getting ValueError: Shapes (10, 1) and (10, 3) are incompatible when training my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

Turning the number of inputs when I call makeModel from 3 to 1 allows the program to run without errors but no training actually happens and the accuracy doesn't change.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import loadtxt
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor as dtr
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae
import numpy as np

def makeModel(num_inputs, num_classes, train_X, train_y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=num_inputs, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)

    return model

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
iris_data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
iris_data = shuffle(iris_data)

iris_data['species'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(iris_data['species'])

feature_columns = ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']

X = iris_data[feature_columns]
y = iris_data['species']

train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
iris_model = makeModel(4, 3, train_x, train_y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LabelEncoder` transforms the input to an array of encoded values. i.e if your input is `["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"]` then they can be encoded as `[0, 0, 1, 2]`. It is not one-hot encoding scheme which is expected by `categorical_crossentropy` loss. If you have a integer encoding you will have to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

#### Fix

change your code loss to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`  :

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

#### Sample

```
def makeModel(num_inputs, num_classes, train_X, train_y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=num_inputs, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)

    return model

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
iris = datasets.load_iris()
y = iris.target
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(y)

train_x, val_x, train_y, val_y = train_test_split(iris.data, y, test_size=0.2)
iris_model = makeModel(4, 3, train_x, train_y)
```

Comment: This fixed it. So if use integer encoding, I use sparse_categorical_crossentropy, but if I use one-hot-encoding then my loss function should be categorical_crossentropy? I'm pretty new to tensorflow, so thank you!